# Bootstrap 4 progress bar fixed across the top

Tags: bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I'm using the sb admin template and I want to place a full width progress bar across the top, but below the "Start Bootstrap" and top menu.

How can I insert the progress bar?

```
<body class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-dark" id="page-top">
  <!-- Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
       ...
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:
Put the progressbar at the end of the nav-Tag and make it 100% width.
The nav-Tag must get "flex-wrap: wrap" because bootstrap 4 works with flexbox and you have to "allow" the line breaks.

Here is a very good flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
      <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
          <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
     ...
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 float-none  progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 41%" aria-valuenow="41" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the nav bar and progress bar in a div element, then add a sticky-top class to it:

```
<div class="sticky-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">
        <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Dashboard">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav sidenav-toggler">
        ...
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       ...
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </nav>

  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 41%" aria-valuenow="41" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```